# Doctrine DQL association Join without limiting results

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have three entities:

### Question

- id
- question
- ...
- choicelist (x-1 with ChoiceList)

### ChoiceList

- id
- name
- choices (1-x with Choice Value)

### ChoiceValue

- id
- value

Each "Question" may or may not have an attached "ChoiceList".  Each choice list may have attached many "ChoiceValues".  The database of questions is huge and we have a lot of choices in each choice list, the website has slowed significantly.

to optimize my database queries, it would make sense to make a single query for all questions and have included in the result ALL needed choice lists and their choices, so not more queries need be made.

SELECT q, cl, cc
FROM Question q
JOIN q.choicelist cl
JOIN cl.choices cc

If I do this, I am under the impression that only questions with a choice list will be joined (so, if the association is not null) such that if a question has no choice list, this query will not return it.

I would like to know how to adjust this DQL such that ALL questions will be returned and IF the question has associated choicelists then they should be returned as well.

Comment: You have tried what exactly?

Comment: I have tried the query posted inside of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do LEFT JOIN:

```
SELECT q, cl, cc FROM Question q LEFT JOIN q.choicelist cl JOIN cl.choices cc
```